# Output a PowerShell object into a string

Tags: string, powershell, format

This code launches ping:

```
$ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$ProcessInfo.FileName = "ping.exe"
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = "localhost"
$Proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$Proc.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo
$Proc.Start() | Out-Null
```

When I type $Proc at the command,

```
$Proc
```

I get this:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
     27       3     1936       1852    10     0.02   6832 PING
```

I want to get the data line into a string.

So I tried this:

```
$Proc | Format-table -HideTableHeaders
```

And I got this:

```
 27       3     1936       1852    10     0.02   6832 PING
```

I tried this:

```
$Foo = $Proc | Format-table -HideTableHeaders
$Foo
```

And got this:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

So the question is... How do you typically get the nice string output from a powershell object into a string?

Ultimately all I'm trying to do is stick the word START in front of the normal output I get when I just type $Proc by itself on a line in my powershell script.

```
START     27       3     1936       1852    10     0.02   6832 PING
```

But, "Start " + $Proc produces this:

```
Start System.Diagnostics.Process (PING)
```

So that's why I thought I'd try to get $Proc into a string.

Comment: Why don't you just pipe it to `Out-String` after `Format-Table`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Something like..

```powershell
$string = $proc | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String

"start" + $string
```

Comment: Cool, Thank you.